# GNU Packages: compiling

Tags: compiling, gcc, editing, gnu

Can someone help me about free software from GNU project. I downloaded some packages, in this case `coreutils` (http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html).
I then started browsing through files and found sources, but after trying to compile any of it it says mainly that `config.h` is missing and after that many others. I tried to run `./bootstrap script`, which I found is meant for checking dependencies and installed all of that, but nothing changed.

I just want to study the code and modify it and run it for myself now, not interested in any `git` committing. I saw a lot about it and am not interested in it now. I will learn `git` later. Just want to know how to edit code and compile it without mess. I read all of the `README` stuff from the project but haven't figured it out.

Comment: What did you install? This is because you are missing the packages needed in order to compile but we can't help unless you tell us something more specific than "installed all of that" :)

Comment: Carefully read the `README*` file(s). For that matter, read all of the files with names in all upper case, especially `INSTALL`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `apt-src` utility. `sudo apt-get install apt-src;man apt-src`. Then, you can:

```
# I keep the sources in ~/apt-src/, 
# you may replace that with a directory of your choice
mkdir ~/apt-src 
cd ~/apt-src
# download the coreutils source + current patches
apt-src install coreutils
# build the unmodified source first  
apt-src build coreutils
```

Now you have buildable, currently-patched sources (and you've seen the noise/valuable information emitted by a build). Proceed as you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Best to start with a tarball then.

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.24.tar.xz
tar -xf coreutils-8.24.tar.xz
cd coreutils-8.24
./configure && make -j $(nproc)
```

Now you can edit files in src/ or lib/ etc. and redo the `make`